# DBI connect failed: ERROR OCINlsEnvironmentVariableGet(OCI_NLS_CHARSET_ID)

Tags: oracle, perl, remote-access, dbi

I'm trying to connect to a remote Oracle database in my perl app. When running the app, the following error appears:

```
DBI connect('//XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1522/TEST','user','password') 
failed: ERROR OCINlsEnvironmentVariableGet(OCI_NLS_CHARSET_ID)
Check NLS settings etc. at App.pm line 28.
```

My App.pm

```
package App;

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;

my $instance = undef;
BEGIN {
    $ENV{OCI_NLS_CHARSET_ID} = "AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251";
    $ENV{ORACLE_HOME} = "path";
}
sub get_instance {
    $instance = bless {}, shift unless $instance;
    return $instance;
}

sub new {
    my ($caller) = @_;
    my $class = ref($caller) || $caller;
    return get_instance($class);
}

sub connect {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{dbh} = DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1522/TEST', 'user', 'password');
}

sub DESTROY {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{dbh}->disconnect if $self->{dbh};
}

1;
```

NLS_PARAMETERS:

```
PARAMETER                                                        VALUE
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
NLS_LANGUAGE                                                     AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY                                                    AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY                                                     $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY                                                 AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS                                           .,
NLS_CALENDAR                                                     GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT                                                  DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE                                                AMERICAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET                                                 CL8MSWIN1251
NLS_SORT                                                         BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT                                                  HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT                                             DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT                                               HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT                                          DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY                                                $
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET                                           AL16UTF16
NLS_COMP                                                         BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS                                             BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP                                              FALSE

19 rows selected
```

I'm using ActiveStat perl on Windows 7. 
Server ORACLE 11.2.0.2.0 x64 on Windows 2003. 
DBI 1.634. 
DBI-Oracle 1.74.

On server, application is running successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Instant Client Oracle libraries? AFAIK Instant client supports only WE8ISO8859P1 and AL32UTF8. Try to use full (thick) Oracle client.

Comment: I'm use the Instant Client Package. Downloaded from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html for Version 11.2.0.2.0 (Instant Client Package - Basic: All files required to run OCI, OCCI, and JDBC-OCI applications)

Comment: On server, application is running successfully

Comment: the server contains the "full" thick client, which supports all charsets.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the appropriate Instant Client packages for your platform from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html.
2. Unzip the packages into a single directory (for example such as "instantclient_11_2").
3. Set your environment's library loading path (for example LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Linux, or PATH on Windows) to the directory created in Step 2.

And it works without:

```
$ENV{OCI_NLS_CHARSET_ID} = "AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251";
$ENV{ORACLE_HOME} = "path";
```